# Jquery showing and hiding div on .hover()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to use the `.show("blind", "slow")` Jquery-ui Effects and the `.hide("blind", "slow")` with `.hover()`. I would like to `.hover()` on the `button` and show the `div`, then by leaving the `button` I would `.hide("blind", "slow")`. The problem is if I leave to quickly and the div is not completely shown, then I will not go back to show to his full height once *hovering* back again.

This is my code and I include the js fiddle

HTML Code

```
<div id="state-slider">
    My Slider
</div>

<button id="trigger">
Button
</button>
```

CSS Code

```
#state-slider {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50px;
    left: -270px;
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: #ff9000;
}
```

Jquery

```
$(function() {
    $("#trigger").hover(function() {
        $("#state-slider").dequeue().stop().show("blind", "slow");
    }, function() {
        $('#state-slider').dequeue().stop().hide("blind", "slow");
    });
});
```

Thanks a lot 
Fabrizio

Comment: The jsfiddle code is different than the one in your question...

Comment: ...and it seems to work

Comment: @Pete sorry, It looks like my jsfiddle was not saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit:

```
$(function() {
$("#trigger").hover(function() {
    $("#state-slider").dequeue().stop(false, true).show("blind", "slow");
}, function() {
    $('#state-slider').dequeue().stop(false, true).hide("blind", "slow");
});
```

try it this way, so it jumps to the end of any animation if you quickly hover over and back again